# RoboVM ApplicationVerificationFailed Xcode - Tried Everything?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, robovm

So I will never understand Apple's certificates/provisioning profiles apparently.

Using RoboVM, I have two devices I test on, an iPad and an iPhone.

So I'm testing on my iPad, all is well. I plug in the iPhone and it doesn't work, gives me the **ApplicationVerificationFailed** error. So I choose a different provisioning profile or something (I forget, maybe the Xcode "wildcard" one) and it worked, don't know why - but it worked.

Cool. So I plug the iPad back in (the one I was just testing on) and no combination of signing identity/provisioning profile would work anymore. No idea why, as I was *just* using this device and now I can't get it to deploy no matter what.

So I eventually go through and delete/revoke all of my certificates/profiles/identities and start fresh. Here's what I'm working with:

[image]

Everything seems to be in order. The correct devices are linked to the profile under my single "Development" signing identity, etc. I've got it all set up in the "Run Configurations" in Eclipse, but it still fails with **ApplicationVerificationFailed**.

---

I even went to Xcode and created an empty project. Upon trying to deploy it I keep getting "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found". My wildcard profile is there and should be valid, it has the appropriate certificate and device linked to it and Xcode obviously "sees" it under Xcode > Preferences > Account etc...

---

I really have no other ideas, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**The date on the iPad was too far in the future, it surpassed the provisioning profile's expiration date. Fixed that and all is good now.**

As for how this occurred, I kept moving the date forward because I needed to check the system prompts for allowing the app access to Photos which only occurs a second time after an uninstall and after some days go by.

Fun times.